# Using nock to make a request made from a docker container?

Tags: node.js, api, docker, jestjs, nock

My end-to-end tests are ran against a local docker environment of a micro service I'm testing, I want to mock out a request made via that docker environment from the end-to-end test but it just doesn't seem to let me.

```
const requestNock = nock('https://google.com').post('/foo').reply(200);

makeRequest('127.0.0.1/bar') // This path then calls https://google.com/bar

requestNock.isDone() // Returns false
```

Is something like this possible? If not is there any solution to mock out an external API's response made via a local docker environment?

Answer (score 0):

This is not something Nock is designed to handle. It works by intercepting outbound HTTP requests inside a single Node process.

Without knowing more about what your docker does it's hard to say what your options are. If the service inside the Docker container has no logic and it's only purpose is to proxy requests during your tests, then I'd argue that it should be removed from the test and you can Nock out the requests inside the single process. I would call these integration tests.

Since you specified your tests are end-to-end, I have to assume the Docker service is more than a proxy. However, you usually don't want to nock any requests of end-to-end tests as it negates the advantages over integration tests.